# For loop works until nested within another for loop, repeating NA values

Tags: r

I need to simulate and then sum the profits over 10 years, where the first year has additional expenses; I also need to see this for several factories with different capacities.  I assumed that a nested for loop would be the easiest way to make this work.

Capacities of factories I want to iterate through: 
`Cap = c(30000, 35000, 40000, 45000, 50000, 55000, 60000)`

If I manually select one of those capacities and use only one for loop:

```
i = 60000
D = rnorm(n=1, mean=50000, sd=12000)
Pr1 = min(D, i)*UnitProf - i*OpCost - i*BuildCost
for (j in 1:9) {
  D = rnorm(n=1, mean=50000, sd=12000)
  Pr2[j] = min(D, i)*UnitProf - i*OpCost 
}
Profit = sum(c(Pr1, Pr2))
Profit
```

I get a single sum of all 10 years' profits (e.g. `619775.10`), exactly what I wanted.

But when I try to iterate through each of the capacities using a nested for loop, such as:

```
Cap = c(30000, 35000, 40000, 45000, 50000, 55000, 60000)

for (i in Cap) {
  D = rnorm(n=1, mean=50000, sd=12000)
  Pr1 = min(D, i)*UnitProf - i*OpCost - i*BuildCost
  for (j in 1:9) {
    D = rnorm(n=1, mean=50000, sd=12000)
    Pr2[j] = min(D, i)*UnitProf - i*OpCost 
  }
  Profit[i] = sum(c(Pr1, Pr2))
}
Profit
```

I get `619775.10 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA …` which repeats a few thousand times.

What I'd like to return is a vector with 7 elements.  The elements being the sum of 10 years of profits, one sum for each factory.

Comment: The issue is that ```i``` means two things in your code - an index and the value of the Cap. You want ```for (i in seq_along(Cap))``` and then you want to do ```Cap_i = Cap[i]``` and replace your non-index ```i``` with ```Cap_i```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your code in a function. Then using some `apply` family function iterate your vector of capacities:

```
Fprofit = function(i){
D = rnorm(n=1, mean=50000, sd=12000)
Pr1 = min(D, i)*UnitProf - i*OpCost - i*BuildCost
Pr2=c() #Empty
for (j in 1:9) {
  D = rnorm(n=1, mean=50000, sd=12000)
  Pr2[j] = min(D, i)*UnitProf - i*OpCost 
}
Profit = sum(c(Pr1, Pr2))
Profit}
Fprofit(60000)
Cap = c(30000, 35000, 40000, 45000, 50000, 55000, 60000)
set.seed(1234) # for being reproducible
sapply(Cap,Fprofit)

#[1]  577403.3  692650.0  769812.6  767271.6  808360.8  859919.7 1046818.9
      # assuming UnitProf=2 OpCost=.02 BuildCost=0.01
```

Edit:

Change the function replacing `Profit = sum(c(Pr1, Pr2))` by `Profit = c(Pr1, Pr2,sum(Pr1,Pr2))` and you will have a complete table of simulations.

Comment: This works excellently.  I was about to try using a custom function & sapply() myself.  Could you help me understand why my nested for-loop was having issues? @Robert

Comment: Well, you need to initialize Pr2 (see the updated function) and Profit before the for loop that assign values; also you cannot assign Profit[i] with i, it will create thousands of empty places

Comment: Why is assigning Profit[i] with i create an issue? I have trouble understanding indexing with more complicated for loops

Comment: If `i = c(1,100)`, then `Profit=c(); Profit[i]=c(20,50)` will create a vector with values at positions 1 and 100 and the other will by NAs. But using `Profit=c(); Profit[seq_along(i)]=c(20,50)` will fill only the first two positions.